# how to Write a boolean parameter in multiPart/form-data in Http request

Tags: http, salesforce, apex, box

Content-Type: multipart/form-data;

In MultiPart/form data
I have something like

`"String header = '--'+boundary+'\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="'+file.name+'";\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream';"
--AaB03x`

I need to add a boolean parameter non_svg = true How to pass it to a multipart/formData

Example :

```
Request   curl ‐F "firstName=Kris" \
                ‐F "publicKey=@idrsa.pub;type=text/plain" \
                echo.httpkit.com
Response     {
    "method": "POST",
    ...
    "headers": {
        "content‐length": "697",
        "content‐type": "multipart/form‐data;
        boundary = ‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐488327019409 ",
        ...
    },
    "body": "‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐488327019409\r\n
    Content‐ Disposition: form‐ data;
    name = \"firstName\"\r\n\r\n
    Kris\ r\ n‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐ 488327019409\ r\ n
    Content‐ Disposition: form‐ data;
    name = \"publicKey\";
    filename = \"id_rsa.pub\"\r\n
    Content‐ Type: text / plain\ r\ n\ r\ n‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐‐ 488327019409‐‐\ r\ n ",
        ...
}


 ‐‐‐‐‐‐488327019409 ==>it is the boundry
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass typed parameters using `multipart/form-data`. You can instead stringify your boolean parameters and pass `non_svg="true"`.